# Build a thin line follower?

Tags: microcontroller, infrared, pid-controller, line

I'm building a line follower robot with just 3 sensors to follow a black line of 1cm. However the distance between my each of my sensors is also 1cm.

Straight path following is not a problem. However there are right angle turns which the sensors seem to miss out often and just run over it. Also, in straight paths, sometimes the line is in between the two sensors and none of them are able to detect and hence its stuck.

How can I solve these problems? Especially the 90 degree turns...

Comment: A, for instance, left 90° turn will have the left sensor suddenly see a line while the right sensor continues to see none and the center sensor continues to see a line. Are you turning left when that happens? You are either driving too fast or not sampling the sensors fast enough.

Comment: move the sensors further apart and run the motors when no line is sensed.

Comment: Your failure at right angles is caused by the system overrunning the turn. At that point, all three sensors are showing background, and the system does not know which way to turn. With your current setup, the only solution is to run very slowly, so the unit can turn 90 degrees in 1 cm. And be aware that giving the unit that sort of turn sensitivity will cause major "hunting" as the unit tries to follow a straight line.

Comment: @Samuel Yes that's exactly what I'm doing currently for the turns (i.e. 1-1-0; [1 -> Sensor sees the line]). This works fine but sometimes there's an offset of the center sensor (moves to the right of the line), just before the turn comes. The left sensor does see the turn, but the center and right sensor don't (1-0-0). I use this condition while the robot is travelling a straight path. If it's (1-0-0), then move slightly towards the right. The same happens at the turns and hence it just keeps going straight and misses the turns.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Would implementing PID help achieving greater speeds? Unfortunately, the setup cannot be changed as per the rules.

Comment: @user87877 - No, a PID would not help. Think about it. If the bot cannot turn in 1 cm, when it encounters a turn it will overrun, and none of the sensors will be able to see the line. What you need to do is implement logic so that if it can't see a line on any sensor it will do something like back up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you read the sensors analogically instead of digitally? If so, do it and interpolate the position of the line with the following formula:

```
e = (-100 * s[0] + 100 * s[2]) / (s[0] + s[1] + s[2]);
```

This is an weighted average of the 3 sensors where s[0] (let's say this is the left sensor) has a magnitude of -100, s[1] (middle sensor) has a magnitude of 0 and s[2] (right) has a magnitude of +100. The weights are the ADC readings from the sensors where white gives a value near 0 and black gives a value near 1023 (assuming your ADC precision is 10 bits as an example). This will give you a value for 'e' between -100 and 100 where e = 0 means that the line is centered, so I like to call this 'the error', hence the variable name 'e'.

If e = 0 you want to go straight. If e < 0, the line is to the left and you want to turn left to correct that, which you probably do by giving your right motor a higher speed than that of your left motor if you are using a differential drive train (the usual way in line followers). Ideally you want to change the relative speeds of the two motors proportionally to the error, that's called proportional control. If the speed of the robot is high enough, you might need to add in derivative control to compensate for oscillations, but you probably need more than 3 sensors to get some benefit out of PD control.

By reading your sensors analogically you will solve the problem where the line is exactly between two sensors.

For the case when the robot loses track of the line, you need to remember what the last error was and use that so that the robot keeps turning towards the line until it finds it.

The code to do this could be something like:

```
void follow_line() {
  int i;
  int lost_line = true;

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (s[i] > BLACK_WHITE_THRESHOLD) 
      lost_line = false; 
  }

  if (lost_line) { 
    if (e < 0)
      e = -100;
    else
      e = 100;
  }
  else { 
    e = (- 100L * s[0] + 100L * s[2) / (s[0] + s[1] + s[2]);
  }

  v_left  = vb - kp * e;
  v_right = vb + kp * e;

  // now set your motor speeds to v_left and v_right
}
```